# Adding network users to _developer group (Leopard Server, Snow Leopard Client)

Tags: xcode, permissions, gdb, osx-snow-leopard

We have a Leopard server and a network of iMacs running Snow Leopard. Some of our users are having trouble running the debugger through XCode as the system asks for a member of the Developer Tools group to authenticate.

Creating a group called _developer in Workgroup Manager and adding the user to it didn't seem to work. Is there a difference between groups added in WGM and the system level groups listed in /etc/group in this case?

Currently there is no _developer group listed on the server in /etc/group.

Does anyone know if creating the _developer group on the server will solve this problem and, if so, how should the group be created (if not through Workgroup Manager).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified approach that I wanted to record here for future reference.

Rather than adding a single user I wanted to add a nested group so that I didn't have to add specific users to each machine.

First, get a list of all available groups and their UUID's.

```
dscl . list /Groups GeneratedUID
```

Then, add the desired group as a nested group of the _developer group.

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer NestedGroups ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF0000000C
```

To confirm that this has been done.

```
dscl . read /Groups/_developer
```

I did these commands straight from Remote Desktop which is great if you have a few machines.